# Virtual host for Symfony2 got httpd.exe application error of memory could not be read

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, symfony, virtualhost

I have a Symfony2 application using MongoDB. It is running fine in the other two PCs - Windows 7 and Linux. I'm migrating it into a new laptop. Its environment is

- Windows 10 Pro
- XAMPP 3.2.2
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0.13 (`php_mongodb` extension 1.2.1 enabled)
- MongoDB 3.4

I successfully run the application at `http://localhost:8000` by running `php app/console server:run`. However, I setup virtual host, let's say `api-site.dev` and when I run `http://api-site.dev`, I got the httpd.exe application error and unfinished page loading.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api-site.dev
    ServerAlias api-site.dev
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\api-site\web"
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]

I will have to setup virtual host because it is an API server and it is needed to call from another Symfony application with MySQL database. I added the following virtual host for the another app `example.dev` and it is running fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias example.dev
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\example\web"
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem persists only for the virtual host `api-site.dev`. It is strange and I have no idea what I should do next.

### [UPDATE]

I traced `/web/app.php` and found the problem occurred at the line `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` when `die('hello')` is removed.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
die('hello');
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
die('hi');
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of [XAMPP 7.0.13 with PHP 7.0.13](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) problem with Windows 10.
I solved the problem by installing [WampServer (x64) 3.0.6](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) which includes

- Apache 2.4.23
- PHP 5.6.25 / 7.0.10
- MySQL 5.7.14

I re-configured everything with WAMP and now working fine.